# Openness of the Interior

Tags: general-topology

I've been working on some problems in introductory topology, and I wanted
some help on formalizing a proof to a problem that I reached. Given the
set $S$ that contains reals, I want to prove that $\mathring{S}$ is open. 
I felt like doing this
via an AFSOC proof around the boundary points of $\mathring{S}.$ Hence,
let's consider the case where $\mathring{S}$ contains at least one of its 
boundary points, say $x$. Then For any $\epsilon>0,$ $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$
is partially contained in $\mathring{S}$ and partially contained in
$$\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathring{S}.$$
Let us fix $\epsilon > 0.$ I can see that if it was the case that
$$(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon) \cap (\mathbb{R} \setminus S) = \emptyset,$$
We would reach a contradiction because knowing that
$$(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon) \cap (\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathring{S})$$
$$=(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon) \cap (\mathbb{R} \setminus (S \setminus 
       \partial S))$$
$$\neq \emptyset,$$
This would imply that $x \in \partial S,$ which contradicts the fact that
$x \in \mathring{S}.$ Hence, I need some help working on the case where
$$(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon) \cap (\mathbb{R} \setminus S) \neq \emptyset.$$

Comment: What is your definition of $\mathring{S}$?

Comment: Echoing Eric Wofsey. What def'n have you been given for Int (S) ? The usual def'n is the union of all open subsets of S, which is of course an open set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a metric space, $x\in \mathring{S}$ if exists $\varepsilon_x > 0$ so that $B(x,\varepsilon_x)\subseteq S$, where $B(c,r)$ is the open ball centered on $c$ with radius $r$.

Note that any point in $y\in B(x,\varepsilon_x)$ also satisfies this property so $y\in\mathring{S}$. Therefore 
$$\mathring{S} \subseteq \bigcup_{x\in\mathring{S}} B(x,\varepsilon_x) \subseteq \mathring{S}$$

Wich implies

$$\mathring{S} = \bigcup_{x\in\mathring{S}} B(x,\varepsilon_x)$$

So since $\mathring{S}$ is a union of open sets, it is itself open.